# How to create a modal popup on click event in a javascript ag-grid cell

Tags: ag-grid

Can please anyone help me with the solution I am looking for? I am trying to create a modal popup in a javascript ag-grid which will popup on click of the cell. This modal contains some of the column fields from grif itself and in addition to this I want to store a few more fields and store the object return from this modal into a grid cell. I am not sure whether I can achieve this or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add `cellEditor for the column in columnDefs` and inside editor add :-

```
   getPopupPosition() {
        return 'over';  //"under"
    }
    isPopup() {
        return true;   
    }
```